# Convert PNG sequence to MP4 from directory

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, png, glob

On a mac I would normally convert a folder of pngs to mp4 using the following:

`ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i -pattern_type glob -i "*" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 10M output.mp4`

Now I'm trying to accomplish the same using windows 10, but globbing is not supported.

Not knowing what the filenames might be, is there a decent way of getting a complete file list of the directory and implementing it with ffmpeg?

Comment: Unless there is a numerical pattern you will have to rename the files or use batch script.

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried the **%** operator ?

> ffmpeg -r 30 -i %.png -vcodec libx264 -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p test.mp4

Comment: That give me the error: `Output file #0 does not contain any stream`

Comment: If u know the extension, can u try `ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i -pattern_type -I %%.your_extension -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 10M output.mp4`

Comment: They are pngs. I tried `ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i -pattern_type -I %%.png -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 10M output.mp4` but I got **Unrecognized option 'I'.**

Comment: Its a typo. Try with -i